# How read an excel file with exceljs stream

Tags: stream, exceljs

I´m trying to read a very large excel file with exceljs. Because the size of the file I´m using an stream.

```js
import * as Excel from 'exceljs';  
import { createReadStream } from 'fs'
@Injectable()
export class ReportingService {
async processParams(path, year : number, month : number, version : number) : Promise < any > {   
     
     // Create a stream from some character device.
      const stream = createReadStream(path)
      setTimeout(() => {
      stream.close(); // This may not close the stream.
      stream.push(null);
      stream.read(0);
    }, 100);


      // const options = {};
    
      const workbookReader = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookReader(stream,{sharedStrings: "cache"})
      var sheet = workbookReader.getWorksheet('Datos')
      for await (const worksheetReader of workbookReader) {
        for await (const row of worksheetReader) {
         this.logger.error('I am in','')
          //here the logic.
        }
      }
      
}}
```

When I run the app the result is an Error:
web_1         | **[NestWinston] Error     12/18/2020, 2:40:39 PM workbookReader.getWorksheet is not a function - {"service":"fs-service"}**
web_1         | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2020:14:40:39 +0000] "POST /fs/reporting/2020/12 HTTP/1.1" 500 52 "-" "insomnia/2020.5.2"

I know the workbookReader is ok created but I can´t create the worksheetReader.
Anybody have some idea??
Thanks!